# Как распечатать файл (file.doc) в c++?

Tags: c++

Не `ShellExecute`.

Comment: Вам нужно чтобы за вас напечатал Microsoft Word? Тогда без аналога ShellExecute не обойтись.

Вам нужно самостоятельно распарсить вордовский документ и распечатать? Геморрой обеспечен, посмотрите на количество кода в OpenOffice, на длину спецификации docx и ужаснитесь. Если не передумали, попробуйте использовать исходники OOo или LibreOffice, но учтите, что они (1) сложные и (2) идут с open-source-лицензией.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. использовать OpenOffice. [Пример](http://habrahabr.ru/post/116151/)
2. использовать MS Word через COM-интерфейс. [Пример](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/34998/MS-Office-OLE-Automation-Using-C)

WARNING!!! офисные пакеты при этом должны быть корректно установлены на ПК, где необходим запуск утилиты, иначе ничего не выйдет...

Еще можно посмотреть аналогичный вопрос на [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/145573/creating-opening-and-printing-a-word-file-from-c)